# jQueryUI switchClass children option has no effect

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I want to use `switchClass` to remove one class from an element and all it's children:

```
$("#things-names-selector").switchClass("disabled", null, {
    children: true
});
```

The problem is that it does update the main element (`things-names-selector`), but it doesn't seem to process its children - they still have the class set.

When I try to remove the class from the element and its children separately, like this:

```
$("#things-names-selector").switchClass("disabled", null);
$("#things-names-selector").children().switchClass("disabled", null);
```

It works as expected (correctly).

What's the problem? Am I missing something? Or is it a problem in jQueryUI?
I am using `twitter-bootstrap` as well, if this has any meaning.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/Leeps8tk/5/) the `jsFiddle`.

Comment: Using `children:true` doesn't actually swap the classes in any children. The only thing it does is that it plays the switching animation on children if it determines it valid (which in theory is there for consistency but in practice is mostly useless). You can use `$("#id, #id *")` if your goal is simply to invoke the method on all elements

Comment: Ah, ok. I think the docs are a bit misleading about it, then. Care to make that an answer, @blgt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments:

Using `children:true` doesn't actually swap the classes in any children. The only thing it does is that it plays the switching animation on children if it determines it valid (which theoretically is good for consistency but I've yet to find a practical use).

You can use

```
$("#things-names-selector, #things-names-selector *").switchClass("disabled", null);
```

if your goal is simply to invoke the method on all elements. [it'll behave identically to what you have but has the benefit of fitting on one line]